# error in uploading image file

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to make a user profile and add a profile picture functionality to it in codeigniter,i simpy copy pasted the file upload code given in the documentation but it is showing error.my view file is

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />
```

my controller is

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('upload');
    }



    public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './images/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    echo'not happening';
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
    }
}
?>
```

it is showing error over here i mean it is echoing 'not happening',which means it is not uploading.if someone can please help me,it will be great.

Comment: What error is it showing?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Does the web server have write permissions for the folder that it is being uploaded to?  there's probably a 90% chance it doesn't and this is permissions related

Comment: if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    echo'not happening';

Comment: i have double checked the permissions.owner dos have the write permissions

Comment: Huh? That's not an error, that's some random code. What is the *actual* error? You may have to look in your error logs on the server.

Comment: can you remove attribute  size="20" and try again

Comment: it's working demo try it https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-upload-image/

Answer (score 1):

Why not you check what is the exact error? I have just updated the code to track exact error what codeigniter is returning.

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{
   $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have loaded the library twice sometimes I found causes issues you have placed one in the constructor and one in the function

Try like below and use `$this->upload->initialize($config);` in the function and load library in the __constructor.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#preferences

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('upload');
    }

    public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
            $config['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = 5000;
            $config['max_width'] = 0;
            $config['max_height']  = 0;

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    echo'not happening';
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
    }
}
```

> Note no need to close codeigniter controllers and models with `?>` as
>   says in user guide

```
application

// Where you upload images to

images

system 

index.php
```